# How to increment by 1 and by 2 in PHP for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, increment

I am trying to increment two separate numbers in the same for loop. For example I want the first number to be:

```
0,2,4,6,8,10 etc
```

I want the second number to be:

```
1,3,5,7,9 etc
```

I have tried what was suggested here but could get it to work:

> [How to increment a number by 2 in a PHP For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831399/how-to-increment-a-number-by-2-in-a-php-for-loop?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

My code so far:

```
$count = count($toyList);
echo $count;
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    $json = '{"toy": {"toyname":"' . $toyList[$i+2] . ',"status":"' . $toyList[$i+3] . '"}}';
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Share `$toyList` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce an additional variable and increase that inside the loop after you have done with it whatever you intend to do. I don't have an environment for PHP at hand, but it should look something like this:

```
$count = count($toyList);
echo $count;
$j = 1;
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    $json = '{"toy": {"toyname":"' . $toyList[$i+2] . ',"status":"' .    $toyList[$i+3] . '"}}';
    $j = $j + 2;
}
```

Comment: If you need more variables, just define more. E.g. one with an initial value of 0, then increase that by two with each iteration.

Comment: `$j+=2;` just syaing

Comment: Yep, the control variable can be increased that way as well, or additional variables inside the loop.